# Bipartite matching in Python

Tags: python, graph, bipartite

Does anybody know any module in Python that computes the best bipartite matching?
I have tried the following two:

1. [munkres](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/munkres/1.0.5.4)

   [hungarian](http://mit.edu/harold/www/code.html#hungarian)

However, in my case, I have to deal with non-complete graph (i.e., there might not be an edge between two nodes), and therefore, there might not be a match if the node has no edge. The above two packages seem not to be able to deal with this.

Any advice?

Answer (score 5):

Set cost to infinity or a large value for an edge that does not exist.  You can then tell by the result whether an invalid edge was used.